# List Comprehension that has more elements than array

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to create an array with list comprehensions like:

```
array = [(x,y)|(x,y,z)<-oldArray, z == 10]
```

Let's say that `oldArray` is a previously made array that has 3 Int values, but the new array I want to make only needs the first two, but whether or not they get added depends on a condition of the third.

I can't tell if this is working correctly or not though.

Comment: It's better to show a simple example of `oldArray` and the expected result.

Comment: Note that `array` is _not_ an array but, well, as list.

Answer (score 3):

The sample code you've written solves the problem you've described.
You filter out elements where z is not 10, and then take only 2 first parts of a tuple to build a new array.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really want to ask is how to debug a haskell program. For this case, just fire up `ghci`, and make your algorithm a little function, and play with it.

```
Prelude> let foo oldArray = [(x,y)|(x,y,z)<-oldArray, z == 10]
Prelude> foo [(1,2,3)]
[]
Prelude> foo [(1,2,10)]
[(1,2)]
Prelude> foo [(1,2,10),(3,4,5),(5,6,10)]
[(1,2),(5,6)]
```

"Working properly" basically means what you really got is what you expected. As we can see, `foo` works fine.

Or we could just use some `print` in the source file, and see if the output  is expected.

For more, you can use `ghci debugger`, or `Debug.Trace`.

---

1. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html
2. https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging
3. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-ghci-debugger